# Unable to load installed gem for New Relic Infrastructure Agent

Tags: ruby, rubygems, newrelic

I am installing `New Relic Infrastructure Agent` on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, e.g.

```
sudo gem install newrelic_ia
```

Then I execute `newrelic_ia --install -a`, it said

```
Unable to load required gem newrelic_rpm
Try `gem install newrelic_rpm`
```

But using the `gem server` it told me...

gem server

```
There are 3 gems installed:
newrelic_ia, newrelic_rpm, rubygems.
```

Any way I can troubleshoot this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the answer you were looking for, but: newrelic_ia isn't officially supported by New Relic. If you're looking for server metrics (CPU, disk, network, etc.), you can use their free [Server Monitoring](http://newrelic.com/features/server-monitoring) agent.

Comment: I want to monitor memcached which the server monitoring does not cover currently.